# /bin/sh: 1: clickhouse: Operation not permitted

Tags: linux, docker, ubuntu, clickhouse, clickhouse-client

I am creating [Clickhouse](https://clickhouse.com/) docker image for version 21.8.11.4, Dockerfile gets build successfully but when I tried to run it using `docker run <imagename>` command, it says `/bin/sh: 1: exec: /usr/bin/clickhouse-server: Operation not permitted`

**Dockerfile:**

```
FROM ubuntu:20.04

ENV CH_VERSION 21.8.11.4

COPY default-password.xml /etc/clickhouse-server/users.d/default-password.xml
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --yes --no-install-recommends apt-transport-https apt-utils dirmngr gnupg 
RUN apt-key adv --keyserver keyserver.ubuntu.com --recv E0C56BD4
RUN echo "deb http://repo.yandex.ru/clickhouse/deb/stable/ main/" | tee /etc/apt/sources.list.d/clickhouse.list
RUN apt-get update
RUN apt-get install --allow-unauthenticated -y clickhouse-client=${CH_VERSION} clickhouse-server=${CH_VERSION} clickhouse-common-static=${CH_VERSION} libgcc-7-dev tzdata libreadline-dev curl 
RUN rm -rf /var/lib/apt/lists/* /var/cache/debconf /tmp/* 
RUN apt-get clean

VOLUME /var/lib/clickhouse

EXPOSE 9000 8123 9009

ENTRYPOINT exec /usr/bin/clickhouse-server --config=/etc/clickhouse-server/config.xml
```

**default-password.xml**

```
<yandex>
    <users>
        <default>
            <password remove='1' />
            <password_sha256_hex>ba7816bf8f01cfea414140de5dae2223b00361a396177a9cb410ff61f20015ad</password_sha256_hex>
        </default>
    </users>
</yandex>
```

**Commands:**

```
$docker build -t clickhouse-server:21.8.11.4 .
$docker run clickhouse-server:21.8.11.4
```

Comment: what if you run it with `--privileged` [flag](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/run/#runtime-privilege-and-linux-capabilities)?

Comment: Please consider accepting an answer if one has been helpful. See [how does accepting an answer work](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work) for info.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This doesn't work because clickhouse requires filesystem privileges that aren't granted when you run a docker image using `docker run <image-name>`

If you want to run your image you could probably do it with:

```
docker run --cap-add=SYS_NICE --cap-add=NET_ADMIN --cap-add=IPC_LOCK clickhouse-server:21.8.11.4
```

[An issue](https://github.com/ClickHouse/ClickHouse/issues/13726) has been recorded on the Clickhouse repository regarding this if you want to read more.